# How to output comma separated values using IFS="," in shell

Tags: shell-script, variable, variable-substitution

I have a small script, which does not give comma separated output when IFS is used, but IFS is mandatory as i need it to read many other value. The output of the below script is `odi_server1 odi_server2`, but I need it separated by comma.

```
#Script Starts
#!/bin/sh

IFS=","
odi_cluster=odi_server1,odi_server2;
echo $odi_cluster;

#Script Ends
```

Current Output = `odi_server1 odi_server2`

Expected Output = `odi_server1,odi_server2`

Note:- `IFS=","` is mandatory, hence removing it is not an option.

Comment: The Input Field Separator is not used for output field separation.

Comment: _Always_ double-quote your variables when you use them, i.e. `echo "$odi_cluster"` instead of `echo $odi_cluster`.

Comment: The shebang must be the first line in the file -- specifically, `#!` must be the first two characters in the script.

Comment: In the suggested duplicate, please read the accepted answer, and particularly the second paragraph of its point (1).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the missing double-quotes coupled with the `IFS` value is exactly the problem

Comment: @roaima Conceded absolutely. As I always quote, and always set IFS as a local export only, I never ventured into this particular morass.

Comment: By the way, you probably could have found that out yourself had you searched for "IFS" in the bash man page and read through the first paragraph with a match.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `$odi_cluster` unquoted in the call to `echo`, the shell will split the variable's value on any character that also occur in `$IFS` (and then perform filename globbing on the generated words).  Ordinarily, `$IFS` contains a space, a tab character, and a newline, but you've re-set it to be a comma.

If the variable's value is `odi_server1,odi_server2` and `$IFS` contains a comma, this splitting results in the two words `odi_server1` and `odi_server2`.  These will be given to `echo` as two separate arguments and `echo` utility will output these with a separating space.

To avoid letting `IFS` have any effect on the output, prevent the shell from splitting the variable's value by quoting the expansion:

```bsh
echo "$odi_cluster"
```

or

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$odi_cluster"
```

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Note that you may set the `IFS` variable for only the `read` built-in utility by invoking `read` like

```
IFS=, read ...
```

This avoids setting `IFS` to a non-default value for the rest of the script.

Possibly also related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Also note that the characters `#` and `!` of the `#!`-line must be the very first characters of the file, and that you don't need to end each statement with a `;` unless there are further statements on the same line.